# Invoke an exe from Visual Studio's toolbar

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, executable, toolbar, invoke

How do you customize a button in a Visual Studio toolbar to run a certain executable?

I use VS2010, so a specific answer would be even better, although this might be the same cross versions...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Under *Tools*, *External Tools* add your executable.

To make it appear in the toolbar then click on the small triangle at the end of the toolbar and select *Add or Remove Button*, then *Customize*. Click *Add Command* and from category *Tools* select *External command 1* (or another if you have multiple).

Comment: After the last step, you can rename the control via "Modify selection".

Comment: I had to choose External Command 8 as my installation of VS2010 arrived with 7 external commands preinstalled